# What happens in vectored interrupt?

Tags: architecture, cpu, instructions

What occurs in a instruction cycle when a vectored interrupt is found?
I also want to know about the vectored data.

I have seen that in the last stage of an instruction cycle there is a step named " interrupt check " and if yes then program is interrupted , but when no interrupt , there is a step named check vectored interrupt , what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

***In a computer, a vectored interrupt is an I/O interrupt that tells the part of the computer that handles I/O interrupts at the hardware level that a request for attention from an I/O device has been received and and also identifies the device that sent the request.***

A vectored interrupt is an alternative to a polled interrupt , which requires that the interrupt handler poll or send a signal to each device in turn in order to find out which one sent the interrupt request.